# environment variables not visible in production

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli

I've built a Vue CLI project with an `.env.development.local` and `.env.production.local` file.

When I run `npm run serve` it loads the variables fine. When I run `npm run build` and serve the dist directory, it doesn't load the variables.

I've made sure the variables are prefixed with `'VUE_APP_'` and when I console.log process.env I get just `{NODE_ENV: "production", BASE_URL: "/"}`

***How can I get the environment variables to be read in production?***

**Edit**: I've included one of my .env files as an example:

```
NODE_ENV=production
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://10.0.0.28:4323/api
VUE_APP_HOME_URL=http://localhost:9098
```

Comment: Seems like you're doing everything right. I assume the .env.production.local file has the same variables as in the .env.development.local? And that the build command in your package.json hasn't been modified to specify a different mode?

Comment: @chrismarx That's right.

Comment: @chrismarx I've included one of the files as an example in the question.

Comment: need more info, like how do you get the .env from your code

Comment: @YongQuan process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL

Comment: i mean how do you load .env into your Vue app

Comment: @YongQuan I don't. Vue does this automatically.

Comment: Here's something to check. Vue inlines the values of the env vars during compile. So after you run build, check out the files in the dist directory, and find your console.log statement. It should look like this: console.log(Object({
                    VUE_APP_API_URL: "etc",
                    VUE_APP_HOME_URL: "etc",
                    NODE_ENV: "production"
                })),

Comment: @blarg - I am trying to get this to work, too. Did you get a solution?

Comment: @WillC, yeh it does work now. I don't have the ".local" suffix on the files anymore though. If you would like to share your code with me, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: @blarg Thanks. I realized that I did not have dotenv installed in this project and adding that fixed it